apex:comandButton not rendering when given an action
I have a VF page with an apex:comandButton. This does not display if i give the action attribute. It renders fine if the action attribute is removed.
To work around it i thought i would create an actionfunction and call the action function from the jquery but this also doesnt work as it throws the error

Uncaught ReferenceError: Save is not defined

If there are any insights that would be great help
<apex:page standardController="ContactPosition__c" extensions="AddReferenceInfo" showHeader="false">
<apex:slds />
<style>
.form-horizontal .control-label{
    /* text-align:right; */
    text-align:left;

    }
    
    .form-horizontal .form-control{
    /* text-align:right; */
    text-align:left;

    }
</style>
 <apex:composition template="{!$Site.Template}" >
    <apex:define name="body" >
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!customCssUrl}" />
        <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages> 
        <div class="slds-scope">
            <apex:form id="Feedback_form" styleClass="slds-form">
                 <apex:actionFunction name="Save" action="{!save}" >                        
                </apex:actionFunction>
                <div class="skillsCSS"> Fill Reference Information </div>
                <apex:repeat value="{!appsRef}" var="ar">
                    <div class="slds-section slds-is-open">
                    <h3 class="slds-section__title slds-theme_shade">
                        <span class="slds-truncate slds-p-horizontal_small" title="Reference Information">1 Reference Information </span>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="slds-section__content">
                        <apex:repeat value="{!RefFields}" var="f">
                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label">
                            {!f.label}
                        </label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ar[f.fieldPath]}" styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </apex:repeat>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                          <!--   Add button
                            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" id="savebutton" />
                            <apex:commandButton value="Save Reference" styleclass="slds-button slds-button_brand"   /> -->
                            
                </div>
                </apex:repeat>
               
                    
                    <!-- <apex:commandbutton action="{!save}" value="Save Reference Info" styleclass="slds-button slds-button_brand"  
                    /> This does not display-->
                                            
                        <a href="#" class="slds-button slds-button_brand saveRef">Save Reference </a>  This displays
                        <!-- <a href="#" class="slds-button slds-button_brand win">Add more Reference </a> This also displays-->
                
                
            </apex:form>
        </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         $('.saveRef').on('click', function () {
            console.log('saving...');
            Save();
         });   
         </script>
    </apex:define>
 </apex:composition>

</apex:page>
